# How to make such a scroll of content?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass

Please help me to style the scrolling of content using react and scss like this:

[image: Example 1]

[image: Update]

So that when the scrolling elements overlap each other, they have something like a parallax style.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve from the image and I think this question may be a little too broad for here.
It would be great if you could provide the code you have so far or something like that, then you will be more likely to get the answers you want.

Comment: so that the scrolling looks like a picture, so that the content when scrolling lay on top of the already viewed content - https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-forest-yu262?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Please add some code on how are you trying to do this and what is the main error/issue you are facing. Just stating that you want something like an image does not help you get help.

Answer (score 0):

a simpler solution would be something along the lines of:

```css
.contentDivContainer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.contentDivs {
  background-color: lightpink;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.contentDivs:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.windowDivs {
  position: fixed;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  left: 100px;
}

.windowDivs2 {
  top: 300px;
}

.windowDivsBlank {
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 2;
  background: white;
  height: 50px;
}

.windowDivsBlank2 {
  top: 250px;
  z-index: 2;
  background: white;
  height: 50px;
}

.windowDivsBlank3 {
  top: 500px;
  z-index: 2;
  background: white;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class='windowDivs'></div>
<div class='windowDivs windowDivsBlank'></div>
<div class='windowDivs windowDivs2'></div>
<div class='windowDivs windowDivsBlank2'></div>
<div class='windowDivs windowDivsBlank3'></div>


<div class="contentDivContainer">
  <div class='contentDivs'>
    ONE - Scroll Up and Down this page to see the parallax scrolling effect. This div is just here to enable scrolling. Tip: Try to remove the background-attachment property to remove the scrolling effect.
  </div>

  <div class='contentDivs'>
    TWO - Scroll Up and Down this page to see the parallax scrolling effect. This div is just here to enable scrolling. Tip: Try to remove the background-attachment property to remove the scrolling effect.
  </div>

  <div class='contentDivs'>
    THREE - Scroll Up and Down this page to see the parallax scrolling effect. This div is just here to enable scrolling.lue Tip: Try to remove the background-attachment property to remove the scrolling effect.
  </div>

  <div class='contentDivs'>
    FOUR - Scroll Up and Down this page to see the parallax scrolling effect. This div is just here to enable scrolling. Tip: Try to remove the background-attachment property to remove the scrolling effect.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/xPtLqDw.png

Thank you, but to make it that way, something like parallax